# How do we check if a value in an array is Null (None) or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, null, nul

my code:

```
import random

print("AI THAT WILL FIND OUT YOUR 5 letter text")
ttt = input()

fin = False
lenof = 25
s = 0
used = []
lol = False
used =  []

five = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

while fin == False:
    for i in five:
        ran = random.randint(s,lenof)
        r = five[ran]
        ran1 = random.randint(s,lenof)
        r = r + five[ran1]
        ran2 = random.randint(s,lenof)
        r = r + five[ran2]
        ran3 = random.randint(s,lenof)
        r = r + five[ran3]
        ran4 = random.randint(s,lenof)
        r = r + five[ran4]
        e = r

        if r == ttt:
            fin = True
            lol = True
            print(">> " + r)
        elif r != ttt and lol == False and used.index(r) is None:
            print("> " + r)
            used.append(e)
```

the error:

```
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
ValueError: 'ntzhk' is not in list
```

So can you please tell me how to check if a value in an array is None or not?

do i need to change anything?

i added that so the program will not repeat the same random letters.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `used.index(r) is None` do `r not in used`.

Comment: You're not checking if a value in the list is `None`, you're trying to check if the value is in the array.

Comment: Hi Programmer, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of :

```
used.index(r) is None
```

you can directly check for existence via:

```
r not in used
```

That showed error as `used.index(r)` doesn't return `None` if not found.